# why there is a "." after the number 3600?

Tags: python, kaggle

```
def time_since_last_project(series):
    # Return the time in hours
    return series.diff().dt.total_seconds() / 3600.
```

~The code is from kaggle course, but why there is a "." after 3600?Please help me~

Comment: Probably to do a floating point division

Comment: The `.` makes it a floating point literal. Without the `.`, it's an integer literal. In older versions of python, dividing an integer by an integer returns an integer. So to get around that, you can divide an integer by a floating point to do floating point division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It specifies the type as `float`.

If you check

```py
# Python2.7
print(type(3600.))
```

You will get that it is a `float`.

Without the period,

```py
# Python2.7
print(type(3600))
```

You get `int`.

This changes the type of division you are using: floating point arithmetic or integer arithmetic.

Look at these two examples to see the difference.

```py
# Python2.7
1 / 2 # = 0
1 / 2. # = 0.5
```

This is the significance of writing `3600.`, the writer of the code wanted to specify to use *floating point division*.

Answer (score 0):

`3600` is an integer while `3600.` is a floating point number. Why one may be preferable to another depends on the division operation being performed. Remember that the objects themselves decide what division means. Since we don't know what `series.diff().dt.total_seconds()` is, there isn't much we can say. If you are dealing with floating point numbers, it makes sense to divide by a float.